# How to be able to write in a file inside a docker image?

Tags: docker

I have a docker image created with the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash seltest
RUN mkdir /home/seltest/output
RUN touch /home/seltest/output/test.out
WORKDIR /home/seltest
RUN chown -R seltest:seltest .
COPY script.sh /home/seltest
USER seltest

CMD ["bash", "script.sh"]
```

which essentially creates a new user `seltest` and then executed the script `script.sh`:

```
echo 'test' > /home/seltest/output/test.out
```

I create the docker image with the following command

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t testimage  .
```

and run it on the host with the following command:

```
docker run --rm  -it  -v ${PWD}/output:/home/seltest/output testimage
```

but I get an error

```
script.sh: line 1: /home/seltest/output/test.out: Permission denied
```

The local folder I created beforehand named `output` is empty.

Why do I get this error? How to set up a shared folder that the docker user `seltest` can write to? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No, I do not want the script to be executed as root. I want the script to run as a normal user

Answer (score 1):

You mount `/home/seltest/output/` from your host OS, so it is has permissions and ownership from host OS. Make it writable for everyone and you won't have a problem in the container:

```
$ chmod 777 ${PWD}/output
$ docker run --rm  -it  -v ${PWD}/output:/home/seltest/output testimage
```

Of course, safer option will be, when you configure write permission with better granularity, not write for all. It can be a problem, because user `seltest` exists only in the container. Better option will be if you define also user id, when you are creating `seltest` user, so you will be to allow write access for that user id on the directory `${PWD}/output` level.

Comment: Yes that works. But in the end I need to do that from within a jenkins job. I hope that will work there too!

Comment: Remember, the _numeric_ user ID is the important thing here; the name of the users in the host and container doesn’t really matter.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your dockerfile to the one below

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash seltest
RUN mkdir /home/seltest/output
RUN touch /home/seltest/output/test.out
WORKDIR /home/seltest
COPY script.sh /home/seltest
RUN chmod +x /home/seltest/script.sh
RUN chown -R seltest:seltest .
USER seltest

CMD ["bash", "script.sh"]
```

**What did I do?**

Set the script copy before you change the owner of the home sub contents. This to avoid permission problems on the script.

**Still permission denied**
After running this you will still have a permission denied problem executing

```
docker run --rm  -it  -v ${PWD}/output:/home/seltest/output testimage
```

**Reason and possible solution**

This is because your user inside your container has **no write** access to the folder that you are mounting from the host system. 
To solve this you can:

1. Give chmod 643 ${PWD}/output
2. Create the user on the host system and than create the user inside the container with the same UID
3. Give the user that has the UID 1000 on you host system write access to the folder: **RUN useradd -u ${UID} -ms /bin/bash seltest**
4. Use the user nobody in the container and set the group rights from the host folder to nobody. Setting the rights on the host can be done by jenkins or by a docker preparation image that starts up, change group, shutdown